# How to view opacity in .eps file after latex+dvi2ps+ps2pdf?

Tags: eps, transparency

I'm trying to use an image with any part with opacity of 50%.

The .eps file is ok, and I can view it well, with the transparent region in a viewer like xnview.

The problem is that when I compile my .tex, and obtain the .pdf file, in this .pdf the opacity doesn't exist.

The .eps file is made with Mathematica 10

My code-example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}

\begin{document}

This is a test.\\
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image.eps}
  \caption{Fact.Region.}\label{regionfact}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{image-opacity.eps}\\
  \caption{Extensión natural de la función, y región factible que nos ocupa.}\label{extensionnatural}
\end{figure}

The cuasi-End.\\

\end{document}
```

The image-opacity.eps is in this link (I can't attach this file)
[image-opacity.eps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmbfldvnpq2fhvq/image-opacity.eps?dl=0)

Comment: Your EPS contains PostScript code without any opacity *and* a TIFF preview image with opacity. `xnview` displays the preview image...

Comment: @PaulGaborit amazing for me!!! :-) So, I think that I can´t export graphs in EPS with transparency from Mathematica 10. This world is close to infinity :-) Thank you

Comment: You may try to export a PDF file from Mathematica (if possible).